# LINQ : Use where clause in a list inside of a list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use where clause in a list inside of a list.

```
list = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,object>();
var sub_list = new Dictionary<string,object>();
sub_list["id"] = 1;
sub_list["status"] = 310;

foreach(var itm in list)
{
  dictionary.Add(itm);
  dictionary.Add("sub_list", sub_list);
  list.Add(dictionary);
}

var showList = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();
showList = list.Where(x => x["name] == "John")
               .Where(y => y.Where(kvp => kvp["status"] == 310)
               .ToList();
```

What is the proper way of using a where clause in a keyvaluepair that is inside of a list?

Comment: You are having a foreach but there is no value on list? This program won't event compile since the dictionary.Add(itm) is requiring you to add the pair value.

Comment: There is no problem using a linq inside a linq. Though I can't help you with your code since it's a bit confusing. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr of course it is only an example.

Comment: @Emad i'm trying to have a condition using the columns of sub_list

Comment: You only describe what you do. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess I know what's your problem. You can perfectly nest LINQ queries and Lambda expressions together and it's perfectly safe to do.

But, you are storing a dictionary in object of another dictionary therefore when you are using `kvp => kvp["status"] == 310` you should cast `kvp` to be `Dictionary<string,object>` and casting objects of dictionaries is risky to do and that's why you should have strongly typed objects (i.e. classes) to store such structure of data.

In short, having

```
showList = list.Where(x => x["name] == "John")
           .Where(y => y.Contains(kvp => ((Dictionary<string,object>)kvp.Value)["status"] == 310)
           .ToList();
```

corrects your problem but having a class with a dictionary property is more OOP.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm getting an error that it cannot convert KeyValuePair<string,object> to Dictionary<string,object>

Comment: Yes, see the edit. You should take the value of kvp first. I told you it's too complex to keep track of.

Comment: Hmm I also tried that but it still gives me the error of cannot convert lambada expression. This is really hard. Sad

Comment: Yes, another change in the code. You get a list with where but it needed a bool inside outer where! So I converted the inner where with `Contains`

Answer (score 0):

Since `list` is a `List of Dictionary of Dictionary`, you'll need to introduce filters (predicates) across the 1 to many relationships using a fold operator, like `.All`, `.Any`, `.First` etc.

As per Emad, it isn't good practice to use very weak types like `object` as you'll need to a lot of casting, first checking for type safety.

I've strengthened the type slightly, although the leaf dictionary values are still weakly typed (hence the need for `.Equals` in the int comparison):

```
var nestedDictionary = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>
    {
        {
            "Foo",
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"Bar", "I'm a string"},
                {"status", 310}
            }
        },
        {
            "John",
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"Bar", "I'm a string"},
                {"status", 310}
            }
        }
    },
    ... next top level dictionary here
};

var showList = nestedDictionary
    .Where(dic => dic.ContainsKey("John") 
        && dic["John"].Any(kvp => kvp.Key == "status" && kvp.Value.Equals(310)))
    .ToList();
```

**Edit**

From the comment, it would seem that you want to strip out a lower level object from the graph (i.e. not just filter on the top level elements).

You can use a `.Select` (returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>>` in your case) or `.SelectMany` (which will flatten out the nested elements):

```
var allJohnsWithStatus310 = nestedDictionary
    .Where(dic => dic.ContainsKey("John"))
    .SelectMany(dic => dic["John"]
        .Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "status" && kvp.Value.Equals(310)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Can I seperate the where clause? Like for example
var showList = nestedDictionary
    .Where(dic => dic.ContainsKey("John") 
    .Where(x = x.Any(kvp => kvp.Key == "status" && kvp.Value.Equals(310)))
    .ToList();

Like this?

Comment: You can separate out the filters in two `Where` clauses, although catenating the two filters with `&&` should yield the same result. It sounds like you are trying to group the subelements somehow (i.e. you don't want the top level elements returned). We can use a `.Select` mapping, or `SelectMany` flattening to do this. Can you clarify your question a bit more please?

Comment: I just want to filter the sub_list by status = 310, and filter also list by name = John. Is this much clearer?